# IIS settings for OutOfProcess .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2012, kestrel

I would like to try OutOfProcess hosting for .NET Core Web App (.NET 5) in IIS 8.
I thought all I need to do is to change hosting model to outofprocess in web.config and IIS will forward request to Kestrel which would host the app.

When I use inprocess hosting model, website is accessible at http://localhost:8080/Test2.
When I change hosting model to outofprocess http://localhost:8080/Test2 returns **HTTP error 502.5** as captured on screen below. Manually starting the app from command line with

> dotnet myApp.dll

makes application available at http://localhost:5000 but I would like to access it thru IIS port.

What do I need to do to access .NET Core App thru IIS when App hosting model is outofprocess?

- I've installed hosting bundle for .NET5 and .NET6.
- I restarted IIS after configurations change.
- I've set folder permission for application pool account, also for
  "everyone" group.
- Reading [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I guess it is not possible to host application like this without modifications to app source code and publishing it again. To be honest I don't understand this article entirely.

*Current host settings [Windows Server 2012 R2]*
[image]

Comment: Open Windows event log and analyze the actual errors there.

Comment: The image of cmd shows that there's no SDK found. So did you install .NET 5 SDK on server?

Comment: @BruceZhang No SDK installed on the server. I thought runtime is sufficient since I only want to run the app.

Comment: It is better to both install SDK and runtime, so please install SDK and try again.